# Data string-to-date procedure

Tags: sql, procedure

Estou criando uma procedure, que recebe uma data string '2015-09-11', verifica se ela é de fato uma segunda feira, se caso não for, ela pega essa data e jogar pra segunda feira da própria semana. Mas meu conceito com sql é bem fraco, a minha base está desta forma.

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_DATA_PARA_SEGUNDA;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DATA_PARA_SEGUNDA (IN SPA_DATA_CONVERTER DATE,INOUT SPA_DATA_CONVERTIDA INT)
    BEGIN            
         SELECT DATE_FORMAT(SPA_DATA_CONVERTER,'%w');
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Agora funciona, mas agora quero retornar esse dateformat na no meu argumento SPA_DATA_CONVERTIDA, como faço?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom Dia Amigo...

Converter data para dia da Semana pode usar o seguinte:

```
SELECT DATENAME ( weekday , '20150911' )
```

Irá Retornar por exemplo sexta! com base no dia você pode montar sua função para acrescentar dias ou remover.. no caso adicionar 3 dias para a Próxima Segunda...
Espero que Ajude!

Para retornar no MySql de uma olhada nos likns:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362722/return-value-from-mysql-stored-procedure
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760414/mysql-stored-procedure-return-value

Comment: Eu vejo algumas funções, mas não sei se tem restrição, eu consigo usar funções tanto do mysql quanto do sql dentro das procedures?

Comment: SERIA ISSO?
`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_DATA_PARA_SEGUNDA;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DATA_PARA_SEGUNDA (IN SPA_DATA_CONVERTER DATE, OUT SPA_NOME_DIA VARCHAR(20)
    BEGIN            
            SPA_NOME_DIA = SELECT DATENAME(weekday,SPA_DATA_CONVERTER);
    END//
DELIMITER ;
`

Comment: Essa que fiz funcionaria no SqlServer.. Para o mySql, De uma Olhada em:   [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235023/1305-function-datename-does-not-exist]

Comment: Espero que Te ajude! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975359/sql-group-by-datename)(http://www.suhailkaleem.com/mssql-datename-alternative-for-mysql/)

Comment: Alterei minha pergunta, agora está funcionando, mas como faço pra retornar qd eu der a call?

Comment: Alterei a Resposta.. Com alguns Links. Provavelmente terá de usar uma variável OUT. ou gravar em alguma tabela..

Comment: EU CRIEI UMA VARIAVEL OUT, MAS COMO QUE EU PASSO O VALOR DO SELECT PRA DENTRO DESSA VAR? EU TENTEI ASSIM,MAS NÃO FOI..
`SET SPA_DATA_CONVERTIDA = SELECT DATE_FORMAT(SPA_DATA_CONVERTER,'%w') as SPA_DATA_CONVERTIDA;`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29048/discussion-between-pachecodt-and-michel-henriq).

Answer (score 0):

Assumo que o primeiro dia da semana é o Domingo, significando que, se passares como parâmetro uma data cujo correspondente dia da semana é Domingo, a stored procedure irá retornar o dia seguinte (Segunda-Feira).

A função [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) devolve o dia da semana ao qual corresponde a data passada como parâmetro. No teu exemplo o dia da semana correspondente à data '2015-09-11' é 6 (1 = Domingo, 2 = Segunda, …, 7 = Sabado)

Sabendo isto, e como segundo esta função, o dia correspondente à segunda-feira é 2, apenas temos que adicionar (subtrair) o número necessário de dias para obter a data desejada.

Eu fiz assim, com certeza existem outras alternativas:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_DATA_PARA_SEGUNDA;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DATA_PARA_SEGUNDA (IN SPA_DATA_CONVERTER DATE,
                                       OUT SPA_DATA_CONVERTIDA DATE)
BEGIN            
     SELECT ADDDATE(SPA_DATA_CONVERTER, INTERVAL 2 - DAYOFWEEK(SPA_DATA_CONVERTER) DAY) 
     INTO SPA_DATA_CONVERTIDA
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Tens aqui um pequeno [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a403/15). Se tiveres alguma dúvida deixa um comentário.

Comment: Excelente..Também tem o `DAYOFWEEK` ...   Achei que precisava do Nome por extenso.. Mas que bom que resolveu, e Gostei da Solução! Abraço